# ListBox and selecting options in WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

What I want to do is, when I select Option 1, and click next to show me a specific dialog, and same for the other two options.

This is my code:

```
<Dialog Id="SelectInstanceDlg" ...>
    .....
    <Control Id="SelectInstanceList" Type="ListBox" X="20" Y="75" Width="290" Height="118" Property="INSTANCE" Sorted="yes">
        <ListBox Property="INSTANCE">
            <ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1" />
            <ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2" />
            <ListItem Text="Option 3" Value="3" />
        </ListBox>
    </Control>
</Dialog>


<Publish Dialog="SelectInstanceDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SelectAuthentication" Order="1">1</Publish> // For Option 1 show specific dialog
```

Doing this without listbox seems easy, but with listbox i just can't figure it out.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your listbox is associated with the property INSTANCE.  However your Publish element (WindowsInstaller ControlEvent)  has a condition of "1" which is always true.  You need to have multiple Publish elements with mutually exclusive conditional expressions ( INSTANCE="1"  INSTANCE="2" INSTANCE="3" )

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried something like <Publish Dialog="SelectInstanceDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SelectAuthentication" Order="1">INSTANCE = "1"</Publish>  but doesn't seem to work, i get the same dialog no matter what option i select. Did I understand correctly ?